# Is there a good, well-known, literal translation of the Japanese "山椒は小粒でもぴりりと辛い"

Tags: translation

I've seen

> 山椒は小粒でもぴりりと辛い

translated as

`japanese peppers small, but hot`

`even if the seeds are small, they are very spicy`

`Sichuan pepper is, even small-grained, piriri (onomatopoeia) spicy.` (is that even a proper sentence?)

`Small head but great wit`

`Sansho is pretty small grain but pretty spicy`

`little head great wit`

`He is short but sharp―small but smart`

`The Japanese pepper is hot with a small grain`

`A grain of pepper may be tiny but it still is sharp on the tongue`

`Within a little head, great wit.`

`Good things come in small packages`

It seems a bit all over the place. I was wondering if there was a good literal translation that is well-known. Any ideas?

Comment: It would helpful for you to provide a word-for-word translation so that we can have some flavour of the original sentence.

Comment: So. What does the original sentence *mean*? We can't give you a good wording for a meaning if you don't tell us what the meaning is.